# Using a System Plug-in (.saver bundle) inside a Cocoa Application as a Resource

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, bundle, screensaver

I'm new with Cocoa / Objective-C development and I have a question.

Last week I had to create a SWF based Screensaver for Mac, and as I didn't find a free-compatible solution for Mac OS X Snow Leopard / Lion, I created a .saver bundle with Xcode 4. It creates inside a webview and loads inside the SWF file.

You must place the SWF file inside the Resources folder inside the bundle to make it work with different SWFs.

And now, I'm trying to code a Cocoa Application to do it automatically.

It has a simple user interface so as the user can select a SWF file. Then the code makes a copy of my previously build .saver file (I have the path hardcoded), places inside it a copy of the SWF file, and saves it where the user indicates in a save panel.

And here comes my question. Now I have the path of the .saver file hardcoded, but I need to have it as a Resource inside my app. Would it be possible? How could I use/access it?

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application already has at least one resource, assuming you didn't delete the MainMenu nib. Add your .saver bundle to that build phase. In the app's code, get the URL to the screen-saver bundle [the usual way](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource%3awithExtension%3a).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to do this but Xcode takes the .saver bundle resources, and not the bundle itself. What I have done is to create a Workspace and I have added both projects into it. Then I had to configure the build settings and I've set the .saver (product of the Screensaver Plug-in project) into "Copy Bundle Resources", one of the "Build Phases" of my app. I could do it directly with drag & drop. Now, if I change something inside the Screensaver Plug-in, when I build my App it takes the last version automatically :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: “I tried to do this but Xcode takes the .saver bundle resources, and not the bundle itself.” What did you drag into the phase? You should be able to drag the .saver product into the phase without creating whole separate project.

Comment: Hi Peter! What I did first is adding the .saver file as Resource without dragging, but clicking on the "+" button and selecting it from file system. I checked with dragging and goes also well, but as said, by adding the Screensaver Plug-in project to my workspace and adding its "Product" (the build .saver file) as Resource, I am able to make changes on it and that the Cocoa App takes its last version.

Comment: @jorditost: That results merely from adding the product to the phase; it does not require a separate project.

Comment: Adding a new target? I did it this way because my first project was already done. I'll try by adding a new target.